# Can't Add css-columns Tag

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

I've tried at least 4 times on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500574/spread-css-columns-horizontally-instead-of-vertically) to add the tag `css-columns`, but each time after I save it disappears. When I type it in the tag box, it shows up and even has a tag wiki associated with it, but it will not stick when I save.

Answer (score 6):

[css](/questions/tagged/css) has [css-columns](/questions/tagged/css-columns) defined as a synonym.

Meaning, that since you have [css](/questions/tagged/css) as a tag, [css-columns](/questions/tagged/css-columns) will not also come up.

Comment: but... css-columns is in no way the same as css... that doesn't make any sense. it's a feature of css...?

Comment: @Jason - The community has decided that for the purpose of tagging, they are the same. In a question, it is enough to tag as CSS to get the right attention to it. I guess people felt that having a css-columns tag was just overly constraining and not really useful.

Comment: @oded it should have been made a synonym of [tag:css3] instead.